# Correct implementation of encryption function

Tags: python, cryptography, encryption

I wrote a simple encryption function that uses argon2d as the KDF and XChaCha20-Poly1305 as the AEAD. Since it is very easy to not get things right when dealing with encryption, I would appreciate if someone could review my script and tell me if it has any vulnerabilities and could be used in the real world to encrypt real data.

```
import argon2
from Cryptodome.Cipher import ChaCha20_Poly1305
import secrets

def encrypt(password, data):
    salt = secrets.token_bytes(32)
    nonce = secrets.token_bytes(24)
    
    key = argon2.low_level.hash_secret_raw(secret=password, salt=salt, time_cost=3, memory_cost=1000000, parallelism=4, hash_len=32, type=argon2.low_level.Type.D, version=19)
    
    cipher = ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key=key, nonce=nonce)
    
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
    
    return salt + nonce + ciphertext + tag
```

Comment: Note for future questions: when reviewing encryption code, it's helpful to also see the corresponding decryptor (even if that's in a different language) and examples of use.  Normally, your test program will show both of these, and it's a good idea to include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add annotations in function parameters, like `password: str` and so on.

Comment: They may be [called something else](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract).

Comment: @greybeard "Annotation" should be fine, although it's a bit general. From your link: "here is a simple function whose argument and return type are declared **in the annotations**:". The syntax is called an [annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), and they're being used as type hints here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether the parameters `password` and `data` should be passed as strings or as byte-arrays.  Use type-hint annotations, or at least a doc-comment so that users know which they should be passing.

Comment: Besides that, would the rest of the code be safe for encryption?